# How to compare VALUE in multimap

Tags: c++, stl, multimap, strcmp

I learnt multimaps are `<key,value>` pair which allows duplicate keys (unlike maps).
Help me to sort a multimap first by *key*(which happens automatically) and then by *value*(i.e name).

```
int main()
{
multimap<int,string>info; // <key,value>
char name[10000];
int age;

//Input till EOF
while (std::cin >> name >> age){                  
info.insert( pair<int,string>(age,name) );
}

//sorted output according to key i.e age
map<int,string> :: iterator i;
for(i=info.begin(); i !=info.end(); i++)
    cout<<(*i).second<<endl;
}
```

Input:

DUCHESS  26
MARIE    8
BERLIOZ  8
TOULOUSE 7
THOMAS   28

Output:
TOULOUSE  7
BERLIOZ   8
MARIE     8
DUCHESS   26
THOMAS    28

Here ages(integers) are keys, so its is first sorted wrt age but if two or more age are same as in BERLIOZ and MARIE then BERLIOZ is desired to be printed before MARIE since **B is alphabetically superior than M**.

Comment: I guess some edit like [this](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Multimap.html)  
: struct ltstr  
{
  bool operator()(const char* s1, const char* s2) const
  {
    return strcmp(s1, s2) < 0;
  }
};
is required but I don't know how to use them!

Comment: Hurray for the Aristocats!

Answer (score 2):

A `multimap` only sorts the keys, not the values.

There are a number of ways you could approach a solution. One way is to go back to using a `map`, but store a `set` rather than a string. This way you get sorting on both keys and the strings within each set.

```
int main()
{
    map<int,set<string>> info;
    char name[10000];
    int age;

    //Input till EOF
    while (std::cin >> name >> age) {
        info[age].insert(name);
    }

    // sorted output
    map<int,set<string>>::iterator i;
    for (i = info.begin(); i != info.end(); ++i)
    {
        set<string>::iterator j;
        for (j = i->second.begin(); j != i->second.end(); ++j)
            cout << *j << i->first << endl;
    }
}
```

The limitation of using a `set` is that the values within a `set` must be unique, so if you have two people with the same name and age it won't work. If that's an issue, you could change to using a `multiset`, or use a `list` and sort the list using `std::sort` once all the names are added to it.

Comment: Multiset would also be an option for the non-unique names instead of list sort.